# More efficient way to save game level state

Tags: objective-c

I'm coding an undo option in my game. The game is a simple match 3 game, with each cell containing a ball, which can be 1-4 colours, so the idea I had was to save the entire grid of ints, and I do this my putting them all into a NSMutableArray, like this...

```
NSMutableArray *currentGrid = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<(mapWidth*(mapHeight*2)); i++)
    {
        [currentGrid addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
    }


    for (int iy=(mapHeight*2)-1; iy>=0; iy--)
    {
        for (int ix=mapWidth-1; ix>=0; ix--)
        {
            int index = (iy*mapWidth)+ix;

            Ball *ball = [self valueAtRowWithArray:tilesArray andColumn:ix andRow:iy];

            [currentGrid setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:ball.ballType] atIndexedSubscript:index];
        }
    }

    [levelStateArray addObject:currentGrid];
```

That works fine, but I'm wondering there's a better/more efficient way to do this. I know nothing of serialisation but I'm wondering if perhaps that could be used somehow to save the array?

Comment: BTW - the whole point of the `NSArray setObject:atIndexedSubscript:` method is so you can do this: `currentGrid[index] = @(ball.ballType);`. Take advantage of modern Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know you could do that, but what's the point of the @? I thought that was just for strings.

Comment: The `@(xxx)` syntax is for wrapping numeric variables (int, float, BOOL, etc) in `NSNumber` objects. It's much easier than using the usual `NSNumber numberWithXXX:` syntax. For numeric constants, you can do `@YES`, `@42`, or `@3.14`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Objective C, so I can't give much in the way of example code (someone could edit and add that though).

The best way to handle an undo method is just to store what changed rather than the entire state. So if the user interacted with a grid cell G and changed its color from A to B, store only G and A. Then, if they hit undo restore grid cell G to state A.

Comment: In these kinds of games the entire grid could be changed (in theory) with a single action, so it's probably always better to just store the entire grid.

Comment: Ah, in that case you might ought to. It depends on how the game is set up. If you have an easy way to tell which cells changed, then you can use that. Otherwise, storing everything may be your only option.